# SVN command line -list of users checking out

Tags: svn

Is there any way to find out the list of users taking checkout of a particular SVN location (using SVN command-line tool)?

Answer (score 1):

You can check server log to see who and when did a checkout or export of a repository. See [SVNBook | High-level Logging](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/operational-logging/).

For example, `svn checkout` and `svn export` actions will show up as "checkout-or-export" events on the log. `svn commit` or `svn import` will be logged as "commit" event.